# MYSQL Incorrect Number of Fetch Variables

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am new to MYSQL. I have a MYSQL table 'MACTrain'. The table looks something like this:

```
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| id   | RSSI1 | RSSI2 | RSSI3 | RSSI4 |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|    1 |   -74 |   -39 |   -68 |   -57 |
|    2 |   -74 |   -43 |   -60 |   -60 |
|    3 |   -75 |   -37 |   -55 |   -59 |
|    4 |   -75 |   -39 |   -52 |   -58 |
|    5 |   -74 |   -39 |   -54 |   -75 |
|    6 |   -71 |   -38 |   -56 |   -73 |
|    7 |   -72 |   -39 |   -60 |   -55 |
|    8 |   -70 |   -37 |   -66 |   -54 |
|    9 |   -76 |   -40 |   -65 |   -57 |
|   10 |   -68 |   -40 |   -60 |   -52 |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I am trying to write a query which will display number of values from id (1 to 2), (3 to 4), (4 to 6), (6 to 8), (8 to 10) which satisfy the following expressions RSSI1 < RSSI2, RSSI2 < RSSI3, RSSI3 < RSSI4, RSSI4 < RSSI1.

So for example the result should look something like this:

(FOR ID 1 TO 2) `2 0 1 0`

(FOR ID 3 TO 4) `3 0 0 0`

(FOR ID 4 TO 6)  `3 0 0 2`

(FOR ID 6 TO 8)  `3 0 2 1`

(FOR ID 8 TO 10)  `3 0 3 0`

I wrote a basic procedure in MYSQL using cursors which does the following for a fixed id range as follows :

```
BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE RSSI1_RSSI2 INTEGER;
DECLARE RSSI2_RSSI3 INTEGER;
DECLARE RSSI3_RSSI4 INTEGER;
DECLARE RSSI4_RSSI1 INTEGER;
DECLARE curs1 CURSOR FOR (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MACTrain where id between 6 and 8 and RSSI1<RSSI2)  
                   union (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MACTrain where id between 6 and 8 and RSSI2<RSSI3)
                   union (SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM MACTrain where ID between 6 and 8 and RSSI3<RSSI4)
                   union (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MACTrain where ID between 6 and 8 and RSSI4<RSSI1);
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
OPEN curs1;
read_loop: LOOP
FETCH curs1 INTO RSSI1_RSSI2;
IF done THEN
LEAVE read_loop;
END IF;
SELECT RSSI1_RSSI2;
END LOOP;
CLOSE curs1;
END
```

I can get correct values for this hard coded range. However i have some issues. The results are displayed as :

```
+-------------+
| RSSI1_RSSI2 |
+-------------+
|           3 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

+-------------+
| RSSI1_RSSI2 |
+-------------+
|           0 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

+-------------+
| RSSI1_RSSI2 |
+-------------+
|           2 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

+-------------+
| RSSI1_RSSI2 |
+-------------+
|           1 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

That is i am getting 4 separate rows. I would like the result to look something like :

`3 0 2 1` i-e 1 row and 4 columns. Right now i am getting 4 separate rows and 1 column.

I tried to use variables RSSI2_RSSI3, RSSI3_RSSI4 and RSSI4_RSSI1 into my FETCH statement. However i get the error Incorrect Number of Fetch Variables. So i would like to know how can i address 2 problems here :

1) I need the query to do these analysis from id's id (1 to 2), (3 to 4), (4 to 6), (6 to 8), (8 to 10) dynamically. Do i need to have an expression for ids so i don't hard code the range?

2) How to display results as 1 row for the fetched values.

I will really appreciate any help that can be provided.

Comment: why are you using cursors?

Comment: I thought since i need to perform row analysis one by one i should use cursors, as this is what i came across during my online search.

Answer (score 1):

How about a single `group by`?

```
select (case when id between 1 and 2 then '1-2'
             when id between 3 and 4 then '3-4'
             when id between 6 and 8 then '6-8'
             else '9-10'
        end) as thegroup,
       SUM(RSSI1 < RSSI2),
       SUM(RSSI2 < RSSI3),
       SUM(RSSI3 < RSSI4),
       SUM(RSSI4 < RSSI1)
from MACTrain
group by (case when id between 1 and 2 then '1-2'
               when id between 3 and 4 then '3-4'
               when id between 6 and 8 then '6-8'
               else '9-10'
          end);
```

Comment: I have a large number of data. Using this example I will need about 48 blocks of cases like when id between 1 and 100, between 101 and 200 etc. Is there a way i can use an expression for ID's to shorten the code?

Comment: @srai . . . You could use a secondary table that maps the ids to their ranges.  You might be able to do simple arithmetic if the ranges are all the same size.  MySQL should be able to handle 48 `when` statements in a single `case`, so that isn't a big problem.

Comment: The ranges are all the same size of 100 but lets  assume the table grows i-e more record are added and the id's increase in size, or lets say i want to test this code on a table which has fewer records then for which the code was written. Instead of modifying the code to add or delete  'when' statement is it possible for the code to process rows automatically? What should be my approach in that case? Will i use cursors in this case or will is use something else?

Comment: And if i wanted the result of the above query to be inserted into a new table how would i modify this query?

Comment: srai . . . You would put a `create table as` before it.

Comment: Sorry i am very new to mysql. Would it be like this create table as TEST_TABLE1 select (case when id between 1 and 2 then '1-2'
             when id between 3 and 4 then '3-4'
             when id between 6 and 8 then '6-8'
             else '9-10'
        end) as thegroup,
       SUM(RSSI1 < RSSI2),
       SUM(RSSI2 < RSSI3),
       SUM(RSSI3 < RSSI4),
       SUM(RSSI4 < RSSI1)
from MACTrain
group by (case when id between 1 and 2 then '1-2'
               when id between 3 and 4 then '3-4'
               when id between 6 and 8 then '6-8'
               else '9-10'
          end);

Comment: No, it would be `create table TEST_TABLE as select . . . `.